# how to limit date range between two month pickers in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#startDate').MonthPicker({
        Button: false,
        SelectedMonth:  -1,
        MonthFormat: 'M-yy', // Short month name, Full year.
        AltFormat: 'mm-yy', // Unix time stamp.
        AltField: '#serverValue' // Selector for hidden input.
    });


    $('#endDate').MonthPicker({
        Button: false,
        SelectedMonth:  -1,
        MonthFormat: 'M-yy', // Short month name, Full year.
        AltFormat: 'mm-yy', // Unix time stamp.
        AltField: '#serverValue' // Selector for hidden input.
    });
```

The question is:

How to accomplish a way to force the user to select 6 months only between these two month pickers given but not more than 6 months ?

Comment: I think you need `daterangepicker`

Comment: With only `MonthPicker` you can't, refer to the comment above.